# How to select a portion of page using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to copy the contents of a page except header and footer only using mouse select+drag+mouseup+ctrl+C kind of copy.

I am using Selenium `Actions` class.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
driver.get("http://connectatgrace.org/im-new/what-to-expect");
builder.click(driver.findElement(By.className("block-holder")))
    .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
    .click(driver.findElement(By.id("footer")));
System.out.println("CLICKED");
```

Is it possible?
Experts please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!!!

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://connectatgrace.org/im-new/what-to-expect");
WebElement content = driver.findElement(By.id("content full-width"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(content, content.getSize().getWidth() / 2, content.getSize().getWidth() / 2).clickAndHold().moveToElement(content, -content.getSize().getHeight() / 2, -content.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
builder.build().perform();
```

Basically you forgot to place height i.e. `getHeight()` instead of `getWidth()`.
Now its working fine.

Comment: So you took my code, fixed a typo, posted it as your own, and accepted it? Hmm

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is the text, you can get it by using `.getText()` on the right element.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://connectatgrace.org/im-new/what-to-expect");
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("main")).getText().trim();
```

---

EDIT

I understand now what you are looking for. I was able to get it to work with the code below.

Basically the code moves the mouse to the bottom-right corner of the element that contains all the desired text, `<div id="content full-width">`. Click and hold the mouse button down, move to the top-left corner of the element, and then `CTRL+C`. I've also validated that the correct text gets into the clipboard.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://connectatgrace.org/im-new/what-to-expect");
WebElement content = driver.findElement(By.id("content full-width"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(content, 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveToElement(content, 
    content.getSize().getWidth(), content1.getSize().getHeight()).release();
builder.build().perform();
content.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "c"));
System.out.println("CLICKED");
```

NOTE: If you use `moveToElement()`, it moves to the *center* of the element. That's why there's code to get the width/height and divide by 2.

---

EDIT 2

After OP noticed that I had a typo, I went back and did some investigations on the `.moveToElement()` methods. From the docs,

> moveToElement(WebElement toElement)
>
> *Moves the mouse to the middle of the element.*
>
> moveToElement(WebElement toElement, int xOffset, int yOffset)
>
> *Moves the mouse to an offset from the top-left corner of the element.*

So corrected the code to use `.moveToElement(e, 0, 0)` to start the selection at the top left of the element and then moved the selection to the bottom right using `.moveToElement(content, content.getSize().getWidth(), content1.getSize().getHeight())`. This should work correctly now.

Comment: No I don't need this. I want the mouse to manually select the contents like a normal human does in front of PC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But by looking onto it I was really excited that it will work. But it is not even moving the mouse. Am I missing something .  I directly copied and pasted your code.

Comment: You won't see the mouse move but you should see the text of the page selected. Just open Notepad or some editor and paste after it's done running and you should see the text of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I copied your code , pasted in eclipse , ran it, browser opened, and after it completed running, I opened notepad and pasted , but it pastes the code that I copied to paste in eclipse. Means something is wrong or missing from my end. Can you guess why I am not getting?

Comment: Do you see the text of the page selected?

Comment: No , However I tried your code in another site and it selects some portion of it .

Comment: You could add a wait for the `content` element... I didn't need it but you may be experiencing some delay where you are located, etc.